# POST to API fails due to routing error even though routes are OK

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

I'm creating my first complete rails API for a tweeter clone, using existing code of another rails application.
The first thing I'm trying to do is to allow the creating of new users through the API, so I have the users controller under: api/v1/users_controller.rb:

```
class Api::V1::UsersController < Api::V1::BaseController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    if params[:follower_id]
      users = User.find(params[:follower_id]).followers
    elsif params[:following_id]
      users = User.find(params[:following_id]).following
    else
      users = User.all.order(created_at: :asc)
    end

    users = apply_filters(users, params)

    users = paginate(users)

    users = policy_scope(users)

    render(
      json: ActiveModel::ArraySerializer.new(
        users,
        each_serializer: Api::V1::UserSerializer,
        root: 'users',
        meta: meta_attributes(users)
      )
    )
  end

  def show
    user = User.find(params[:id])
    authorize user

    render(json: Api::V1::UserSerializer.new(user).to_json)
  end

  def create
    user = User.new(create_params)
    return api_error(status: 422, errors: user.errors) unless user.valid?

    user.save!
    user.activate

    render(
      json: Api::V1::UserSerializer.new(user).to_json,
      status: 201,
      location: api_v1_user_path(user.id)
    )
  end

  def update
    user = User.find(params[:id])
    authorize user

    if !user.update_attributes(update_params)
      return api_error(status: 422, errors: user.errors)
    end

    render(
      json: Api::V1::UserSerializer.new(user).to_json,
      status: 200,
      location: api_v1_user_path(user.id),
      serializer: Api::V1::UserSerializer
    )
  end

  def destroy
    user = User.find(params[:id])
    authorize user

    if !user.destroy
      return api_error(status: 500)
    end

    head status: 204
  end

  def messages
    messages = User.find(params[:id]).messages
    render json: ActiveModel::ArraySerializer.new(messages, each_serializer: Api::V1::MessagesSerializer).to_json
  end

  def followed
    followed = User.find(params[:id]).followed
    render json: ActiveModel::ArraySerializer.new(followed, each_serializer: Api::V1::UsersSerializer).to_json
  end

  def followers
    followers = User.find(params[:id]).followers
    render json: ActiveModel::ArraySerializer.new(followers, each_serializer: Api::V1::UsersSerializer).to_json
  end

  def follow
    current_user_id = User.where(api_token: request.headers['X-Api-Key']).pluck(:id)
    Follow.new({follower_id: current_user_id, followed_id: params[:id]}).save
    respond_with 
  end

  def unfollow
    current_user_id = User.where(api_token: request.headers['X-Api-Key']).pluck(:id)    
    Follow.where('followed_id = ? AND follower_id = ?', params[:id], current_user_id).destroy_all
  end  

  private

  def create_params
    params.require(:user).permit(
      :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :username
    ).delete_if{ |k,v| v.nil?}
  end

  def update_params
    create_params
  end  
end
```

After calling a post using Postman:

```
Started POST "/api/v1/users/create?email=fabriciofreitag@gmail.com&password=[FILTERED]&password_confirmation=[FILTERED]&username=fabriciofreitag" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-01-05 13:40:02 +0100
```

I get the following error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/api/v1/users/create"):
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:84:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  /home/fabricio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /home/fabricio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /home/fabricio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'
```

If I run "rake routes":

```
fabricio@fabnot:~/Desktop/little_tweet$ rake routes
         Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                            Controller#Action
 users_sign_out GET    /users/sign_out(.:format)              devise/sessions#destroy
                POST   /:controller(/:action(/:id(.:format))) :controller#:action
                GET    /:controller(/:action(/:id(.:format))) :controller#:action
           root GET    /                                      messages#index
   api_v1_users GET    /api/v1/users(.:format)                api/v1/users#index
                POST   /api/v1/users(.:format)                api/v1/users#create
    api_v1_user GET    /api/v1/users/:id(.:format)            api/v1/users#show
                PATCH  /api/v1/users/:id(.:format)            api/v1/users#update
                PUT    /api/v1/users/:id(.:format)            api/v1/users#update
                DELETE /api/v1/users/:id(.:format)            api/v1/users#destroy
api_v1_messages GET    /api/v1/messages(.:format)             api/v1/messages#index
                POST   /api/v1/messages(.:format)             api/v1/messages#create
 api_v1_message GET    /api/v1/messages/:id(.:format)         api/v1/messages#show
                PATCH  /api/v1/messages/:id(.:format)         api/v1/messages#update
                PUT    /api/v1/messages/:id(.:format)         api/v1/messages#update
                DELETE /api/v1/messages/:id(.:format)         api/v1/messages#destroy
api_v1_sessions POST   /api/v1/sessions(.:format)             api/v1/sessions#create
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

post url should be `/api/v1/users`, not `/api/v1/users/create`

Read document: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions